# Filtering data programmatically on SPView

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, filter

I would like to know how can I filter information in SharePoint list (Library of documents) programmatically. I have tried 2 ways but they don't solve my problem:

- Using the string `lsWebPart.FilterString`. It creates a filter, but then the user is able to remove that filter in the interface, so it's not a good solution.
- Using `SPView.Query`. It modifies the view but I don't need to modify it, just to show different filters based on some user parameters.

In my site I would like to filter the same library of document by a column called 'Nationality'. So depending on the nationality of the user connected (I retrieve that from Active Directory) I would show different data. If I can' make that via code, I would need to create a view for each country (but that is not efficient and will need constant updates for new countries).

Are there other possible ways to filter the information of a list in my code?

**UPDATE:**

Do you mean something like that 'Aviw'?

```
  SPListView docview = list.Views["MyView"];       
  var docquery = new XElement("Where",
           new XElement("Eq",
           new XElement("FieldRef", new XAttribute("Name", "Nationality")),
           new XElement("Value", new XAttribute("Type", "String"), "xxxx")
           )).ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);

           docview.Query = docquery;
           docview.Update();
           lsWebPart.ViewGuid = docview.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
```

**SOLVED**:

```
SPList list = web.Lists["mylist"];//Evalee Docs
ListViewByQuery listviewByQuery = new ListViewByQuery();
listviewByQuery.List = list;
SPQuery query = new SPQuery(listviewByQuery.List.DefaultView);
query.Query = "Here your CAML expression";
listviewByQuery.Query = query;
```

Comment: How does this work? Do I have to create webpart with a document library in it and apply this code??

Answer (score 2):

Use SPGridView or SPListViewByQuery instead of SPView.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listviewbyquery.aspx.

Comment: I update the post.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.
Use SPGridView or SPListViewByQuery.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listviewbyquery.aspx