# Powerful list filtering

Tags: list, list-view, custom-list, visual-web-part

I need to extend the functionality of the default list (specifically for a document library) to include more powerful filtering. This includes being able type free text search and to have filters which allow **multiple selections**.

The closest existing solution I've found is [Sapiens](http://www.sapiens.at/en/products/pages/filter-webpart-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx), however it is not displaying lookup fields and it doesn't allow multiple filter selections.

I think I'm going to have to extend the list myself to make something suitable. My issue is that I'm not sure how to stick a document library in a Web Part, as XSLTList or List is not an option in the SharePoint section of the ToolBox.

I've seen [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30620/filtering-data-programmatically-on-spview) post about adding custom filters to list, but it doesn't go into any detail about how its implemented.

Thanks very much for any help.